# CDF - Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

If the CDF is defined: 
 $F_X\left(x\right)=\:1-e^{-λx}\::\:x\ge 0\:and\:0:\:x<0$ 
But when we substitute $x=0$ in the equation $1-e^{-λx}$ we got $0$. 
So why we can't say that: 
 $F_X\left(x\right)=\:1-e^{-λx}\::\:x>0\:and\:0:\:x\le 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the CDF of an exponential distribution which is a continuous distribution. As such it’s CDF is expected to be continuous so the left- and righthand limits of $F_X$ at $0$ should coincide.

As a result both of your definitions are valid and equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements are true. The reason we usually write the first is that although the CDF is $0$ at $x=0$, the *density* isn't. The PDF is $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, which is $\lambda$ at $x=0$.

Writing the CDF in the first way makes clearer the distinction between $x\geq0$, where the denisty is positive, and $x<0$, where the density is $0$.

---

As Ian points out, the above is probably not technically rigorous (although it is a good intuitive reason as to why we should lump $x=0$ together with the points $x>0$, rather than with the points $x<0$).

A more rigorous answer, as Stefan hints at, is that the set $x\geq0$ is the *support* of the distribution, i.e. the smallest closed set $S\subset\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X\in S)=1$. So it makes sense to define the CDF separately for two types of points in $\mathbb R$: those in the support of $X$ (i.e. $x\geq0$), and those not in the support of $X$ (i.e. $x<0$).

Comment: +1 Good point on the density being positive. Maybe a word on the distributions support might give additional insight.

Comment: Actually, the density is never *really* defined at any particular point (since you can always tweak it at just that point and recover another density for the same distribution). This is pedantic at Lebesgue points, since there is a "best" value of the density at each Lebesgue point. But it is not really pedantic at non-Lebesgue points. $0$ is the only non-Lebesgue point for the exponential distribution, and as a result $f_X(0)$ has no "best" definition. Most people would probably prefer the density to be either left-continuous or right-continuous, but even that is artificial.